# mongoose - update multiple documents asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm finding several documents in collection, modifying some of them and I want to save them to database. The only thing I've come up with is looping through documents array and saving them one by one like this:

```
var len = documents.length, i = 0;
while(i < len) {
  documents[i++].save();
}
```

Is there more sophisticated way to to this?

EDIT: Here is an example document:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  data: [{ // array of sub-documents
    value: 1337,
    quantity: 1410
  }, ...]
}
```

I'm pushing a sub-document containing different values to each document, so I cannnot just use `Model.update`.

Comment: There is a much more efficient way, would be helpful if you could add some details of the update operation by including some test documents and the modification detail.

Comment: @chridam Hi, thanks for having a look at this. I added some info as you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the update, still trying to follow your question. Do you mean you want to update some subdocuments in the `data` array, say for instance changing the `quantity` field to 1411 for the document with `value` 1337?

Comment: I don't want to update values existing in document, I want to `.push()` new sub-document to `data` array. Sorry if I was unclear at first.

Comment: Oh ok, so are there any conditions in pushing the new subdocuments to the `data` array, say perhaps for documents with `name: 'foo'` push the new sub-document or you are just arbitrary adding them?

Comment: That's my issue, I can't adress any certain characteristic of a document  so it's impossible to use `Model.update()`. I'm just adding new sub-documents.